# Проверка переменной, переданной методу

Tags: php, массивы, ооп, методы

Есть библиотека, которая требует передачу конфигурационного массива. Массив формируется на бэкэнде и передается из контроллера. Может вообще не передаваться или передаваться не со всеми ключами, тогда используется конфиг, заданный по умолчанию в библиотеке. То есть, пользовательского ввода нет в любом случае.

Вопрос. Нужно ли делать метод-валидатор для проверки всех элементов массива на `is_numeric()`, `is_string()`, `strlen()` и так далее, с выбросом эксепшенов, в случае несоответствия ключей требованиям. Или можно указать в гайде требования к массиву, сделать пару эксепшенов на совсем уж критические ошибки и предположить, что разработчик постарается передавать корректные данные сам.

Просто валидатор разрастается до 60% размера самой библиотеки.

P.S. Код будет выложен на гитхаб. Поэтому хотелось бы услышать любые советы для реализации красивого кода, какие вы можете дать. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: используйте библиотеку валидации от symfony

Comment: Библиотека пишется под Laravel, Zend и YII, недостатка в валидаторах нет. Просто сам массив сложный. Валидация очень громоздкая выходит. Все равно желательно ее включить?

Comment: Так я же и говорю - возьмите валидатор, пропишите правила, вызывайте на входе библиотеки валидатор, и получите свое желаемое уменьшение boilerplate-кода.

Comment: А, ну да. Так я не подумал. Спасибо.